# Using a created Helper method in the Views - rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

i'm new to rails so any help or advise would be much appreciated. i am trying to call up a created helper method called "trackable_thing" in my views file but i get the error message:

`wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)`

[activities/index.html.erb]: I originally had in my views file:

```
<h1>Activities</h1>

<% @activities.each do |activity| %>
  <% trackable_thing = activity.trackable %>
  <% if trackable_thing.respond_to? :name %>
    <% name = trackable_thing.name %>
  <% elsif trackable_thing.respond_to? :content %>  
    <% name = trackable_thing.content %>
  <% end %> </br>
  <%= link_to activity.owner.firstname, activity.owner if activity.owner %> created the event "<%= name %>"</br>
<% end %>
```

[activities_helper.rb]: But I wanted to convert the below logic code in the views to a helper method and place it in the activities_helper.rb file - so i wrote the below helper method

```
activities/index.html.erb (code changed to a helper method as below)
<% trackable_thing = activity.trackable %>
<% if trackable_thing.respond_to? :name %>
   <% name = trackable_thing.name %>
<% elsif trackable_thing.respond_to? :content %>  
    <% name = trackable_thing.content %>
<% end %>

activities_helper.rb
module ActivitiesHelper
  #identifies if the trackable_thing is an event or comment
  def trackable_thing
    trackable_thing = activity.trackable
    if trackable_thing.respond_to? :name 
      name = trackable_thing.name
    elsif trackable_thing.respond_to? :content
      name = trackable_thing.content
    end
  end
```

[activities/index.html.erb]: I am trying to call up the helper method in the views but i am unsure how. I called it as shown below:

```
<h1>Activities</h1>
<% @activities.each do |activity| %>
  <% trackable_thing %>
  <%= link_to activity.owner.firstname, activity.owner if activity.owner %> created the event "<%= name %>"</br>
<% end %>

error message states: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
```

I also tried calling it as below but i get an error:

```
<h1>Activities</h1>
<% @activities.each do |activity| %>
  <% trackable_thing (link_to activity.owner.firstname, activity.owner if activity.owner %> created the event "<%= name %>")</br>
<% end %>

error message states: syntax error
```

Any advise or help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You have to pass an `activity` to the method. `trackable_thing activity`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yea what ptd said, trackable_thing doesn't know what activity is. Make that method take a parameter, name it whatever you want as long as when you call it you pass in the activity.